# How to use memcached with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

How to use memcached server?

I have following script and need to be using memcached:

```
$dbserver="server";
$dbuser="user";
$dbpass="pass";
$dbname="db";
function dbcon(){
  @$spojenie=mysql_connect($GLOBALS["dbserver"],$GLOBALS["dbuser"],$GLOBALS["dbpass"]);
  mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
  if (!$spojenie){
    die('error');
  }
  mysql_select_db($GLOBALS["dbname"],$spojenie);
  return $spojenie;
}
$dbspojenie=dbcon();
$GLOBALS["dbspojenie"]=&$dbspojenie;
```

Comment: It is not clear what is asked here. What exactly memcached should be used for?

Answer (score -2):

Read manual [memcache](https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.connect.php)

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('memcache_host', 11211);
```

Comment: thank you, i had to use new Memcache instead of memcached, because memcached class is not present (should i install it from somewhere?) and i have got error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqlnd_memcache_set()